# optaplanner: how to enforce planning variables values to be used only once

Tags: java, optaplanner

I am trying to learn optaplanner. And as a learning project I am trying to implement a very basic and simple program which calculates "[magic squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square)".

Basically I am trying to assign "Number"s to the "Box"es defined in rows and columns.

Sorry for not copy/pasting directly from source code, my development machine can not connect  to internet so I will try to write down important part of classes by hand.

My domain structure is as follows:

> @PlanningSolution 
>   MagicSquareSolution
>
> ```
> //facts
> List<Column> columnList
> List<Row> rowList
> List<Number> numberList
>
> //entity
> List<Box> boxList
>
>
> @valueRangeProvider (id="numberRange")
> getNumberList()
>
> @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
> getBoxList
> ```

---

> @PlanningEntity 
>   Box
>
> ```
> Column column
> Row row
> Number number // planningVariable
>
> @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs="{numberRange}")
> getNumber
> ```

I am using a SIMPLE Java score calculator class.

In my solver configuration xml I used FIRST_FIT and FIRST_NON_DETERIRATING_SCORE.

The problem is; in the solution I got, numbers are reused like

```
7 5 3
1 5 9
7 5 3
```

Here you can see although the sum of rows and columns are equal to 15;
Numbers 7,5 and 3 are used multiple times.
How can I enforce the all the values in the value range for the planning variable is used at least once and only once.

Thanks.

Akif,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a score constraint:

```
when
     Box($n : number, $id : id)
     Box(number == $n, $id > id)
then
     // -1 hard
```