# Optaplanner: how efficiently enforce one-to-many constraint?

Tags: optaplanner

I prepare example with `easyScoreCalculatorClass` and `incrementalScoreCalculatorClass` (Java score counting) to solve problem with power consumers and power suppliers (phones and chargers, where voltage must be equal and consumer required ampere must be not greater then supplier provided ampere, and each supplier has cost).

Optaplanner make solution for sample with 2 consumers and one supplier which is not desired as I expected that one supplier can't operate on two consumers in one time and solution must end with at least -1 value fro hard score.

To enforce one-to-namy constraint I see possibility by maintaining map with count how many times suppliers assigned to consumers. Is that one possible solution to enforce constraint in Java code?

Is that possible to organize data or mark fields with annotations so this constraint automatically enforced?

I look to [optaplanner: how to enforce planning variables values to be used only once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22335179/optaplanner-how-to-enforce-planning-variables-values-to-be-used-only-once) but don't understand how to map Drool code to Java...

Comment: If it's truly a oneToMany relationship (and not a oneToOne), have you considered inverting your model? So instead of assinging People to Seats, assign Seats to People. So instead of having a PlanningEntity Person with a planning variable getSeat, use a PlanningEntity Seat with a planning variable getPerson.

Comment: Seems that it is one-to-one relation. Thanks for correction. I choose side for entity that have no `null` value for planing variable. Is one-to-one relation have special support to enforce avoiding multiply assignment of same variable or 1-to-n same as 1-to-1 for this?

Comment: No, just add a hard constraint that they should be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Several of the examples have uniqueness constraint that you describe. For example, in the n-queens example all rows must be different. That example has a java score impl too.

Comment: For easy scoring method I see code: `if (queen.getRowIndex() == otherQueen.getRowIndex()) score--;`. For incremental  scoring method I see usage of counting map: `rowIndexList = rowIndexMap.get(rowIndex); score -= rowIndexList.size();`. Seems that map based solution - typical for such problem. Is it possible to define move generator that avoid duplication by maintaining map of already used values of planing variables?

Comment: Also interesting comparing how slow Drools `this.id < that.id` constraint to avoid duplication vs map based solution with incremental Java scoring...

Comment: The `this.id < that.id` in DRL is to only match queen A and B, but not match queen B and A or match queen A and A.